# Why is my gradle build not loading the most recent dependency?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradlew

In most of our gradle projects we have the following dependency:

```
compile('com.xxx.yyy.zzz:ch-commons:+')
```

According to our understanding of the documentation, this is supposed to retrieve the most recent version of `ch-commons` from our maven repository.

***tl;dr***

Our actual "most recent version" is `1.7.0-SNAPSHOT`, but gradle is *actually* retrieving `1.6.0-SNAPSHOT`.

***The whole story***

Our repository configuration is as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://local-repo/artifactory/apps-release-local' }  // company application release builds
    maven { url 'https://local-repo/artifactory/apps-snapshot-local' } // company application snapshot builds
    maven { url 'https://local-repo/artifactory/repo1' }               // company lazy mirror of central repos
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

I have verified that there are no `ch-commons` artifacts in any of these locations except `apps-release-local`. And in `apps-release-local` we have the following contents (sha1, md5, and metadata files elided):

```
Index of apps-snapshot-local/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/ch-commons

Name                          Last modified      Size
../
1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/               07-Apr-2016 16:09    -
1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/               08-Apr-2016 11:03    -
1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/               08-Apr-2016 14:32    -
1.0.4-SNAPSHOT/               13-Apr-2016 12:33    -
1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/               15-Apr-2016 12:37    -
1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/               17-May-2016 13:16    -
1.2.1-SNAPSHOT/               18-May-2016 14:28    -
1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/               14-Jun-2016 15:42    -
1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/               17-Jun-2016 11:57    -
1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/               17-Jun-2016 13:42    -
1.5.1-SNAPSHOT/               21-Jun-2016 16:16    -
1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/               22-Jun-2016 09:27    -
1.6.2-SNAPSHOT/               30-Jun-2016 22:02    -
1.6.3-SNAPSHOT/               01-Jul-2016 10:42    -
1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/               01-Jul-2016 13:34    -
```

Looking inside the `1.7.0-SNAPSHOT` directory we have the following contents (same stuff elided):

```
Index of apps-snapshot-local/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/ch-commons/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT

Name                                                  Last modified      Size
../
ch-commons-1.7.0-20160701.183333-1-sources.jar        01-Jul-2016 13:34  14.54 KB
ch-commons-1.7.0-20160701.183333-1.jar                01-Jul-2016 13:34  22.19 KB
ch-commons-1.7.0-20160701.183333-1.pom                01-Jul-2016 13:34  2.21 KB
```

The contents of `apps-snapshot-local/com/xxx/yyy/zzz/ch-commons/maven-metadata-2.xml` are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.xxx.yyy.zzz</groupId>
  <artifactId>ch-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3-20160701.154200-1</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.6.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.6.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20160701183429</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Furthermore, if we change the dependency declaration to reference the explicit version:

```
compile('com.xxx.yyy.zzz:ch-commons:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT')
```

it then works "correctly", retrieving the correct version `1.7.0-SNAPSHOT`.

---

So, why then isn't the dependency setting with the `+` version wildcard retrieving the most recent version?

Comment: What the maven metadata file states as the latest?

Comment: I actually bumped to ```1.7.0-SNAPSHOT``` after posting this question. So that is what ```maven-metadata-2.xml``` says is the latest. But my local builds are still retrieving ```1.6.0-SNAPSHOT```.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, gradle **caches** SNAPSHOT dependencies for 24 hours.
You can refresh them manually with

```
--refresh-dependencies
```

Or you can configure the cache durations as per the guide: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:cache_refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can also set changing to true so it doesn't cache snapshots

implementation group: 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz', name: 'ch-commons', version: '1.7.0-SNAPSHOT', changing: true